# can't pick date again in datepicker modal after swal fire alert

Tags: jquery, alert, sweetalert2

My HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="start" class="form-control" value="">
<input type="text" id="end" class="form-control" value="">
<input type="text" id="pay" class="form-control" value="">
```

My JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#start,#end").bootstrapMaterialDatePicker({

        startView: "days",
        autoclose: true,
        format: "DD MMMM YYYY", 
        weekStart: 0, 
        time: false,    
    });

    $("#end").change(function () {
    var startDate = document.getElementById("start").value;
    var endDate = document.getElementById("end").value;
 
    if ((Date.parse(endDate) <= Date.parse(startDate))) {
        // alert("End date should be greater than Start date"); //default alert
         $('#end').modal('toggle'); //hide modal when end date is smaller than start date
        Swal.fire({                 //trigger the swal alert

            icon: 'error',

            title: 'Validation',

            text: 'End date should be greater than Start date',


        });
        $('#end').modal('show'); //after alert, input the end date again (not working)
        document.getElementById("end").value = "";
    }
    });
}
```

Screenshot:

[image]

The validation process worked, but when I clicked OK, the alert didn't immediately close, and I can't select the date in datepicker modal again.

[image]

I tried `$('#end').modal('toggle');` and `$('#end').modal('show');` but it's not working.

Question:
How can I hide the alert modal, and select the date again?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide a working fiddle for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has some issues :

1. `Change` event is fired when the user clicks the `ok` button. it will automatically close the date picker, so you don't need to manually close it. (Note that `Swal.fire` is async.)
2. you shouldn't manually close/open the datepicker modal, it breaks the event handlers in it. instead you can open the datepicker with `$("#date").focus();`
3. `Swal.fire` is async and returns a promise. so you shouldn't put the code for reopening datapicker next to it, instead you should use `Swal.fire(...).then(v => {...})`.

Full code ([Run the code on codepen](https://codepen.io/ya3ya6/pen/YzqrXeQ?editors=1010)):

```
$("#date").bootstrapMaterialDatePicker({
    format: "DD/MM/YYYY",
    lang: "fr",
    weekStart: 1,
    time: false,
    startView: "days",
    autoclose: true
});

$("#date").change(function (e) {
    Swal.fire({
        icon: "error",
        title: "Validation",
        text: "End date should be greater than Start date"
    }).then((v) => {
        $("#date").focus();
    });
});
```